# SQL - Given sequence of data, how do I query the origin?

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

Let's assume we have the following data.

```
|  UUID |       SEENTIME      |     LAST_SEENTIME    |
------------------------------------------------------
| UUID1 | 2020-11-10T05:00:00 |                      |
| UUID2 | 2020-11-10T05:01:00 |  2020-11-10T05:00:00 |
| UUID3 | 2020-11-10T05:03:00 |  2020-11-10T05:01:00 |
| UUID4 | 2020-11-10T05:04:00 |  2020-11-10T05:03:00 |
| UUID5 | 2020-11-10T05:07:00 |  2020-11-10T05:04:00 |
| UUID6 | 2020-11-10T05:08:00 |  2020-11-10T05:07:00 |
```

Each data is connected to each other via LAST_SEENTIME.

In such case, is there a way to use SQL to identify these connected events as one? I want to be able to calculate start and end to calculate the duration of this event.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also show the results that you want; that is also not dlear.

Comment: Sorry I edited the tag

Comment: Is the UUID same for connected events?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive CTE.  The exact syntax varies by database, but something like this:

```
with recursive cte as 
      select uuid as orig_uuid, uuid, seentime
      from t
      where last_seentime is null
      union all
      select cte.orig_uuid, t.uuid, t.seentime
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.seentime = t.last_seentime
    )
select orig_uuid,
       max(seentime) - min(seentime) -- or whatever your database uses
from cte
group by orig_uuid;
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.  I use AWS Athena to make query and unfortunately, Athena does not support recursive CTE.  Do you happen to know of other way without recursive CTE?

Comment: Indeed, Presto has experimental support for WITH RECURSIVE since version 340 (https://prestosql.io/docs/current/release/release-340.html). @hinewwiner you can deploy a recent version of Presto on AWS, or do the calculation in your application layer.